# JSP code or web server config to call CSS files hosted in a CDN?

Tags: jsp, dns, cdn

I have JSP files which calls css and image files hosted in a CDN like below.

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnname/test.css"
img src="http://cdnname/modal-lineSeparatorDown.png" alt=""
```

The cdnname (cdndev.abc.com, cdntest.abc.com etc) changes by the tier (dev, test, stage and production). I thought of adding a config to the webserver (.htaccess or httpd.conf) to match the css and images and redirect or write code (JSTL) to get the hostname and decide where to direct for the css and/or images.

Which is the better option?

The second option seem to make the JSP pages look ugly with too many repetitive code as i have lot of images and reasonable number of CSS per page.

The first option seem to have some performance issue.

Can somebody advise? How does yahoo, google etc handle this issue?

thanks a bunch !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not set the target CDN in the environment and use something like ${env.resourceurl}/ to prefix all your resources?

this way you can have as many environments as you need (dev1, dev2, ci, test, etc.) and you don't need to know anything about them in the code, you just expect the environment to match the world the code runs in.